# Azure SNMP problems

Tags: azure

I want to setup a monitor system in Azure. The monitor system is using snmp protocol.

However, I have some problems.

My monitor system private subnet is not same as other hosts. 
I also tried to use public address. On my mac, I tried to use snmpwalk to azure public IP (VM and also allowed 161 in Azure firewall policy) which return Timeout.
(e.g snmpwalk -v2c -c xxx AzurePublicIP system)

Any suggestion can let me use snmpwalk from VM1 to VM2 (different subnet?)

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestion can let me use snmpwalk from VM1 to VM2 (different
>   subnet?)

If the Azure VMs in the different subsets of **the different virtual network**, you need make sure the VMs can communicate with each other in the different virtual networking using [Virtual network peering.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) If the Azure VMs in the different subsets of the same virtual network, by default, they can communicate with each other without any further steps.

Moreover, you need to add inbound security rules of [NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic#create-a-network-security-group) which is associated with the VM2 subnet to allow SNMP ports and UDP protocol access to your subnet.

- UDP 161: Used when management stations communicate with agents, e.g. Polling
- UDP 162: Used when agents send unsolicited Traps to the management station

Also, check the firewall inside each of Azure VMs.

Hope this helps.